# why does qgraphicsview only draw when program finishes?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, drawing, redraw

Sorry if there were question like this around but I couldn't find them.

I am trying to draw some QRects to QGraphicsScene embedded in QGraphicsView on the main window for every n-th iteration of my algorithm. The problem is that only the view of the last iteration is drawn and nothing is being rendered before.

mainwindow.h:

```
...
QGraphicsScene* scene;
QGraphicsView* view;
...
```

mainwindow.cpp: in constructor

```
view = ui->graphicsView;
scene = new QGraphicsScene();
```

On every n-th iteration this function is called:

mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::drawSchedule(jss::JssTabuBack jobShop) {

    scene->clear();
    view->setScene(scene);

    //...some calculations...

    //add a square: 
    scene->addRect(QRectF(...));

    ...

    view->show();
    scene->update();
    view->update();
}
```

But the graphicsView stays unchanged until the program finishes. I'm new to Qt so I don't know if I should actually use QGraphicsView for what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Are you returning to the event loop between each iteration?

Comment: heh, probably not, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you have a call to QCoreApplication::exec() anywhere (normally in your main() function)? Also how is drawSchedule called?

Comment: @Jan This is my main.cpp:

    `QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.showFullScreen();
    return a.exec();`

I figured QCoreApplication is only used for console applications. 

drawSchedule is called like this:

    `while(...) {

        if (totalIters % 1000 == 1) {
            
            drawSchedule(jobShop);
        }`

Comment: First, you'll need to use QApplication, since you're using widgets. Secondly, you never give control back to the eventloop in your loop; the solution to that depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish; re-drawing periodically, adding something every n-th second etc.